# Executing multiple commands in the same function (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I am trying to execute few statements in my function in Haskell,
I looked online and got the idea that may be if I use "do" I can be able to do that.I used that but it still is not working for me, If some one can please have a look and guide me what I am doing wrong, I have just started with haskell, so its a little struggle with Haskell syntax.

My function:

```
type Rod = String
Move = (Integer, Rod, Rod)
hanoi :: Integer -> Rod -> Rod -> Rod -> [Move]
hanoi n source helper destination= if n==1 then [(n source destination)] else do
                                (hanoi (n-1) source helper destination) 
                                ([n source destination]) 
                                (hanoi (n-1) helper destination source)
```

I am trying to do the towers of Hanoi problem.and I want to execute the three statements that are after "do". Any help would be highly appreciated .

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Haskell is an expression-oriented language. Everything on the RHS of an `=` (or `->` in case expressions) is an expression.`do` blocks are fancy expressions, but not appropriate for this use case. For your case, you really should think about what the *result* needs to be.  Then write an expression describing it.

Comment: I think you are pretty close - you just have to realize that you don't want to *do* something - indeed you are trying to return a `list` of moves - you have to *concat* the results somehow ;) .... also to the downvoters: shame on you - this is a good question - maybe not PhD level but please keep the community friendly to beginners!

Comment: @Carsten Thank you for such sweet, kind and motivational comment, I will try to think of concating the result.Its good to hear that I am some what close to the solution :) Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to help you out a bit here is a way to get it to compile and work (well almost):

```
type Rod = String
type Move = (Integer, Rod, Rod)

hanoi :: Integer -> Rod -> Rod -> Rod -> [Move]
hanoi n source helper destination =
  if n==1 then
    [(n, source, destination)]
  else
    hanoi (n-1) source helper destination 
    ++ [(n, source, destination)]
    ++ hanoi (n-1) helper destination source
```

the things I changed are:

- gave a type for `Move` (I hope you wanted a tuple)
- changed the results into tuple (`(n source destination) -> (n,source,destination)`)
- concatenated the results with `++`

Now you only have to fix a slight problem with the order of the operations ;) and it should print you a solution :D

Comment: Thank you a millions, indeed this was what I was struggling with. Thank you for being so kind and helpful!!!!! :)